# Image access permission issue using OpenLayers

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, openlayers

I am having a problem loading an image using the OpenLayers library. I am trying to load an image that is stored on the device dynamically. If I declare the options manually everything works as expected. If I try to load the image through path using `file://...` I get the following error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files/projects/1/layers/volume.png

To resolve this error I used the [Ionic Web View](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/webview) path converter: `window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc()` .

But this gives me another error, now related to CORS, considering that the access method now uses HTTP GET, which I quite don't understand since I trying to load a local image and not a remote one:

> Access to image at 'http://localhost/_app_file_/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files/projects/1/layers/volume.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   GET http://localhost/_app_file_/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/files/projects/1/layers/volume.png net::ERR_FAILED

If I include the file in the assets folder and try to upload it, everything works as expected, but it's not how I want it to work.

---

**Working code (manually configured):**

```
let layerImage = new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
        url: 'assets/layers/volume.png',
        crossOrigin: '',
        projection: 'EPSG:31982',
        imageExtent: layerExtent
    }),
    name: "layerImage",
    visible: true,
});
this.map.addLayer(layerImage);
```

**Not working code (dinamically configured inside a for loop):**

```
let filePath = this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'projects/' + this.projectId + '/layers/' + filename);
let layerImage = new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
        url: filePath,
        crossOrigin: '',
        projection: 'EPSG:31982',
        imageExtent: layerExtent
    }),
    name: "layerImage",
    visible: true,
});
this.map.addLayer(layerImage);
```

I saw in some related questions that this can be caused by debugging with Chrome, but the same problem happens if I not use it.

Comment: Do you need to access the canvas data?  If tainted canvas is not a problem you could remove `crossOrigin: '',`

Comment: Okay, this solved the issue. I ended up focusing on other things and let this option go unnoticed. I swear I thought to myself before asking this question: Will it be Mike who will enlighten me again in this OL question? Thank you very much one more time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Mike comment, the problem is solved if I remove the `crossOrigin: ''` option from `Static`.

```
let layerImage = new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
        url: filePath,
        projection: 'EPSG:31982',
        imageExtent: layerExtent
    }),
    name: "layerImage",
    visible: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use url paramater as a function, maybe that helps.

```
const convertFileSrc = this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc;
let layerImage = new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
        url: (extent) => {
            return convertFileSrc(this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'projects/' + this.projectId + '/layers/' + filename);
        },
        crossOrigin: '',
        projection: 'EPSG:31982',
        imageExtent: layerExtent
    }),
    name: "layerImage",
    visible: true,
});
this.map.addLayer(layerImage);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in the question comments you can see that @Mike already discovered the issue. Basically the problem was occurring because of the `crossOrigin` option.